# shaderfrog runtime does not update shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I am trying to implement ShaderSrog- shaders with the ShaderFrog Runtime Library like advised here under Vanilla JavaScript.

https://github.com/AndrewRayCode/ShaderFrog-Runtime

1. The shaders do load but they do not.... shade, which means there is no movement on the geometry's surface.
2. The only three.js version it worked with so far is r71 although this site talks about news for a thre.js r91 candidate which it does not work with:

https://github.com/AndrewRayCode/ShaderFrog-Runtime/pull/22

Here is the code so far. Please be so kind and tell me what I am missing.
Maybe someone can also tell me which is the highest three.js- version shaderfrog runtime works with.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried three.js version 91 and the now actual r106 which both lead to an error in the shaderfrog runtime which says:

"d.default is undefined"

Also I tried different shaders and geometries which are // commented.

```
function model_viewer(){

    var that = this;


this.init_three_js  =   function(){

    this.runtime            =   new ShaderFrogRuntime       ();
    this.scene              =   new THREE.Scene             ();


    this.camera             =   new THREE.PerspectiveCamera ( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    this.scene              .   add                         ( this.camera );
    this.runtime            .   registerCamera              ( this.camera );

    this.camera.position.z  =   5;

    this.clock              =   new THREE.Clock             ();

    this.container          =   document.getElementById     ( 'side_frame' );

    this.renderer           =   new THREE.WebGLRenderer     ();
    this.renderer           .   setSize                     ( $(this.container).width(), $(this.container).height());

    this.container          .   appendChild                 ( this.renderer.domElement );

//    document.body           .   appendChild                 ( this.container );
};//


this.load_shader    =   function(){ 

//    that.runtime.load( './classes/js/New_Composed_Shader.json', function( shaderData ) {
    that.runtime.load( './classes/js/Universe_Shader.json', function( shaderData ) {

    // Get the Three.js material you can assign to your objects
    that.material               =   that.runtime.get( shaderData.name );
//    that.material.needsUpdate   =   true;
}); 

    var geometry    =   new THREE.BoxGeometry       ( 6, 2, 2 );
//    var geometry    =   new THREE.PlaneGeometry     ( 5, 20, 32 );

    this.cube       =   new THREE.Mesh              ( geometry, that.material );
    this.scene      .   add                         ( this.cube );

};//


this.animate    =   function() {

    requestAnimationFrame( that.animate );

    that.runtime            .   updateShaders   ( that.clock.getElapsedTime() );
    that.cube.rotation.y    +=  0.02;

    that.renderer           .   render          ( that.scene, that.camera );
};


this    .   init_three_js       ();`enter code here`
this    .   load_shader         ();
this    .   animate             ();


}//class
```